# How much GPUs are needed for Image ehancement?

Tags: neural-network, gan, gpu

I'm looking for a GPU to train my model. Most of the papers that I have followed used 2 or more gtx 1050ti card or higher. ([MIRNet](https://github.com/swz30/MIRNet), [EnlightenGAN](https://github.com/AselSiriwardena/EnlightenGAN)) I need to that how much GPU power will it take to train my model. I need to estimate my resources before I start my research. I have a very tight budget not more than 1200$. will a Lenovo legion 5 ( ryzen 7, 16gb ram, 1660ti 6b ) will be enough for that? should I go for an RTX 2060 or higher? or can you suggest any other options.

I want to know will it be enough to train those models.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone with the RTX. If I was to design deep learning models,I would be prefer more number of cores in the GPU , where RTX is the winner.

Lets not forget the Tensor cores which are present in RTX , which makes it stand out for Deep Learning processing. (Faster Tensor operations).

Go with RTX if you can afford it.

```
 ╔════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
 ║      GPU       ║ GTX-1660Ti ║ RTX-2060 ║
 ╠════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
 ║ GPU-cores      ║ 1536       ║ 1920     ║
 ║ Tensor-cores   ║ N/A        ║ 240      ║
 ║ RT-cores       ║ N/A        ║ 30       ║
 ║ Texture-units  ║ 120        ║ 120      ║
 ║ Render-outputs ║ 48         ║ 48       ║
 ║ Base-clock     ║ 1500       ║ 1365     ║
 ║ Boost-clock    ║ 1770       ║ 1680     ║
 ║ Mem-bus-width  ║ 192-bit    ║ 192-bit  ║
 ║ Mem-bandwidth  ║ 288GB/s    ║ 336GB/s  ║
 ║ Mem-capacity   ║ 6GB        ║ 6GB      ║
 ║ TDP            ║ 120W       ║ 160W     ║
 ╚════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Is it enough for train a model like EnlightenGAN?

Comment: GAN needs high Vram to load models and 6gb is pretty low.  https://lambdalabs.com/blog/choosing-a-gpu-for-deep-learning/